# How to use ViewBinding in Adapter with ItemViewType

Tags: android, adapter

i have an `Adapter` for `Recyclerview` that i use for a chat, so i inflate 2 layout's in the `onCreateViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        if (position == MY_MESSAGES) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_right_chat, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_left_chat, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }
```

I used the same `ViewHolder` since i instantiated with `ButterKnife`, however now i want to use `ViewBinding` but i don't know how i could use a single `ViewHolder` if i have to generate a binding object for each layout.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should use merge adapter for different view in recyclerView. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter. In each adapter, you generate a binding, so you could use it it each layout. may be this tutorial may help you: https://blog.mindorks.com/implementing-merge-adapter-in-android-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've enabled `ViewBinding` from `build.gradle`, Android will create separate binding model for each layout resource with `layout` tag at root. Hence, you should consider using two different `ViewHolder` class as a cleaner approach where you can obtain the `binding` model for each layout: `ItemRightChatBindingModel` & `ItemLeftChatBindingModel`.

Comment: In this case to differentiate which bind function from one of the `ViewHolders` i am going to call, i would have to check the position field of the `onBindViewHolder` as I do in the `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: @jeanf Why do you need to differentiate the bind function? Each view holder can have it's own complete implementation, common parts you can extract as utility or extension functions.

Can you explain or post your exact use case here, I might be able to help out more then?